# Trying to make something an array of objects disappear when loop ends

Tags: processing

I made a game where you use the mouse to make a rocket move to try to avoid hitting the asteroids falling down the screen. I have everything working right, but when the loop ends after an asteroid and rocket intersect, asteroids still stay on the screen. I am trying to get rid of the asteroids when the loop happens, but I'm not sure how.

Here is the link to my game if you want to see what is going on but it only works on processing: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/810719/embed/?plusEmbedHash=ZjhmZWQ4YTFlZGViNWUzOTczYmU3MDBmMzY3ZTE5OWRiNzFiYWE3MDNlZjA2YzMxMmVmNTgyNDNlNjdmYWFjMWUxMjhlNTJmODc5ZGVkZjY0ZTYwZDg3YmM4NzJhNDk2ZDhmYjY0OGQ3Y2MwYWQzNDViMjlhNDI4Y2M3MDlhYmRtSEFHMGxJejA5MTV2dFd1c3pOQmE3Y0RDSGRiYm5WakFkYUlxVzBsQmc2Z1QvWnhUQjh6amExektLU256OHpWSHpFcThvSTZZbHMxOC9PRjJQTSttdz09&plusEmbedTitle=true

This is what I have so far:

```java
void draw() {

    background(0, 0, 230);
    m = millis();

     //when game restarts the game will restart at 0 seconds rather than the time from the 
    previous game played 
     gameTime = millis()- startTime;


    //displays time is in seconds
    textSize(60);
    fill(232, 98, 82);
    text(gameTime / 1000, 790, 60); 


    // displays instructions about how to play the game
    fill(232, 98, 82);
    textSize(60);
    textSize(15);
    text("*Press a key for a little suprise while playing", 15, 20);
    text("*Move mouse to avoid the asteroids", 15, 38);

    rocket1.display();
    rocket1.face();

    //loop through Asteroid objects and move them.
    //even though array is [100], only loop through the ones you want to see (numAsteroid)
    for (int i=0; i<numAsteroid; i++) {
    myAsteroidArray[i].display();  
    myAsteroidArray[i].move();    
    myAsteroidArray[i].topPop();  


    if (rocket1.intersect(myAsteroidArray[i])) {
      //when the rocket hits an asteroid loop will stop and display the text and a circle

      noLoop();

        gameOver = true;
        ////xPosition, yPosition, xSpeed, color
        background(57, 169, 219); 
        //display text for instructions about the game
        fill(232, 98, 82);
        textSize(60);
        text(0, 255, 0);
        text("Click Circle to Play", 191, 370); //if can't figure out timer do double click
        textSize(15);
        text("*Press a key for a little suprise while playing", 15, 20);
        text("*Move mouse to avoid the asteroids", 15, 38);
        fill(232, 98, 82);
        stroke(232, 98, 82);
        ellipse(width/2, height/2 + 40, 50, 50);
        //use circle so the rocket doesn't get stuck in "no loop". it just so the user can press the screen to move the rocket away from the collision
        textSize(60);
        fill(255);

        text("Time:" + gameTime/1000, 330, 500); //displays the time from the game the user had just played and lost
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know that `noLoop()` is sexy and everything, but in your case I would suggest to avoid using it. For several reasons, but the main one is that you won't be able to call `mousePressed()` or `keyPressed()`, and on your game over screen it seems like that's something that you would like to do.

Instead, you can use your `gameOver` boolean to split the draw loop into drawing the game or drawing the game over screen and get a similar result. Here I've hastily thrown an example of what it could look like:

```
void draw() {
  if (gameOver) {
    DrawGameOverScreen();
  } else {
    DrawGame();
  }
}

void DrawGame() {
  background(0, 0, 230);
  m = millis();

  //when game restarts the game will restart at 0 seconds rather than the time from the 
  //previous game played 
  gameTime = millis()- startTime;


  //displays time is in seconds
  textSize(60);
  fill(232, 98, 82);
  text(gameTime / 1000, 790, 60); 


  // displays instructions about how to play the game
  fill(232, 98, 82);
  textSize(60);
  textSize(15);
  text("*Press a key for a little suprise while playing", 15, 20);
  text("*Move mouse to avoid the asteroids", 15, 38);

  rocket1.display();
  rocket1.face();

  //loop through Asteroid objects and move them.
  //even though array is [100], only loop through the ones you want to see (numAsteroid)
  for (int i=0; i<numAsteroid; i++) {
    myAsteroidArray[i].display();  
    myAsteroidArray[i].move();    
    myAsteroidArray[i].topPop();  


    if (rocket1.intersect(myAsteroidArray[i])) {
      //when the rocket hits an asteroid loop will stop and display the text and a circle

      //noLoop();

      gameOver = true;
    }
  }
}

void DrawGameOverScreen() {
  ////xPosition, yPosition, xSpeed, color
  background(57, 169, 219); 
  //display text for instructions about the game
  fill(232, 98, 82);
  textSize(60);
  text(0, 255, 0);
  text("Click Circle to Play", 191, 370); //if can't figure out timer do double click
  textSize(15);
  text("*Press a key for a little suprise while playing", 15, 20);
  text("*Move mouse to avoid the asteroids", 15, 38);
  fill(232, 98, 82);
  stroke(232, 98, 82);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2 + 40, 50, 50);
  //use circle so the rocket doesn't get stuck in "no loop". it just so the user can press the screen to move the rocket away from the collision
  textSize(60);
  fill(255);
}
```

It solves your graphical problem quite nicely, and then let you handle what you want to do next (if that's something you planned to do). Have fun!